# How to do this query in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to select data from multiple tables in laravel. How can I do a query like this in laravel?
Here is my query which I want to use in laravel with pagination

```
$blog = DB::select("select blog_post.*,(select img_name from blog_image WHERE blog_image.bid=blog_post.bid limit 0,1) as img_name, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM likes WHERE likes.bid =blog_post.bid) AS likes,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM comment WHERE comment.bid =blog_post.bid ) as comments ,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM blog_share WHERE blog_share.bid =blog_post.bid ) as  share 
    from blog_post WHERE status=1 AND is_draft=0 AND is_publish=1 AND is_delete=0")->paginate(2);
```

Comment: Show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty standard query. First, you need to create a model for each table and [define relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in the `BlogPost` model.

To count relations, use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method.

Comment: Can you please give me an example ?